# Enumerating interfaces in device info set obtained for a specific PnP enumerator

Tags: c, windows, winapi, setupapi

I'm trying to get device interfaces data via `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces()` for all devices which correspond to a specific PnP enumerator. Consider the following example (for interface with index 0 only):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <SetupAPI.h>

static int get_interface(HDEVINFO);

int main()
{
    HDEVINFO devInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevsA(NULL, "USBSTOR", NULL, DIGCF_ALLCLASSES | DIGCF_PRESENT);
    if (devInfoSet == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SetupDiGetClassDevsA: Error %lu\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    int ret = get_interface(devInfoSet);

    SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(devInfoSet);
    return ret;
}

int get_interface(HDEVINFO devInfoSet)
{
    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA devIface = { sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA) };
    if (!SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(devInfoSet, NULL, &GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK, 0, &devIface))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces: Error %lu\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

(A more complete version of this example is available [here](http://pastebin.com/jpzjcgrk).)

Upon running that, `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces()` fails with `GetLastError()` returning error 259 (`ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS`), as if there weren't any interfaces for the device info set to begin with. It seems to be the behavior for all device info sets obtained for *device setup classes* rather than *device interface classes*.

However when I add `DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE` flag to the last argument of `SetupDiGetClassDevsA()` call, so that the set is obtained for interface classes, the latter fails with error 13 (`ERROR_INVALID_DATA`). The same error usually ensues in case of device setup classes when the PnP enumerator specified is not registered within the system. Indeed, when I replace the enumerator argument with `NULL`, the interface is obtained successfully. [According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551069.aspx), specifying `DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE` flag allows the use of a device instance id in place of the enumerator argument, but it occurs to me that aforementioned device instance ids and `NULL` are the only options for `SetupDiGetClassDevs()` call's enumerator argument, when it has `DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE` flag present, with *actual* enumerators being out of option in the case.

Could you please explain me, what is actually going on here? I'm not familiar with SetupAPI semantics so I can't tell what limitations would getting device info set for *device setup classes* have imposed, in contrast with that for *device interface classes*. Also, could there be some version-specific behavior in here? The code above was tested on Windows 7 x64 system, but itself was being compiled into a 32-bit executable. I need to know specifically if any particular solution proposed for this would work on good ol' Windows XP as well.

**P.S.** Not a duplicate of [Getting device path for CreateFile while enumerating devices with SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526233/getting-device-path-for-createfile-while-enumerating-devices-with-setupdienumdev), despite similar underlying purpose. ;)